# Side nav is not taking full page height in IE11

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, internet-explorer

I need the sidebar to fill 100% of the page height, but when the page length increases, the sidebar's height is not increased in IE11 but in chrome, the sidebar is taking full page height.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

React Code -

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

CSS -

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please, instead of posting an img, put the code, this way others can reproduce your problem

Comment: Please **copy and paste** the code instead of putting an image of the code. We can't copy code to test from an image. Please provide a code snippet which can **run and reproduce** the issue. You can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).